# Tailwind(flowbite) pop-up showing black screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I'm building a dashboard with flowbite and tailwind in laravel, but I'm really struggling with pop ups.

I'm using the [flowbite](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/modal/#pop-up-modal) pop-up modal model, but when i copy and paste the code into my project and try to toggle the pop up it's only showing a black screen.
The dropdown, tooltips etc are working correctly as almost every other component.

I've also tried to take another modal model from flowbite but others are not showing at all, so i assume that there must be something wrong in my configurations.

This is the modal I'm trying to use :

```html
<button class="block text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button" data-modal-toggle="popup-modal">
  Toggle modal
</button>

<div id="popup-modal" tabindex="-1" class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-50 md:inset-0 h-modal md:h-full">
  <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-md h-full md:h-auto">
    <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
      <button type="button" class="absolute top-3 right-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="popup-modal">
          <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>  
      </button>
      <div class="p-6 text-center">
        <svg class="mx-auto mb-4 w-14 h-14 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-200" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 8v4m0 4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
        <h3 class="mb-5 text-lg font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Are you sure you want to delete this product?</h3>
        <button data-modal-toggle="popup-modal" type="button" class="text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-300 dark:focus:ring-red-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2">
            Yes, I'm sure
        </button>
        <button data-modal-toggle="popup-modal" type="button" class="text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-200 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 hover:text-gray-900 focus:z-10 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-600">No, cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my my webpack.mix :

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-tailwind');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix
   .version();

   
}
```

And here's my tailwind config.js ;

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/js/**/*.vue',
    "/node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/ui'),
    require('@tailwindcss/custom-forms'),
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ]
}
```

Also, I've installed tailwind via npm and I'm importing in my app.js the flowbite js files like so :

```
require('../../node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.js');
```

Everything is correctly working, but this pop ups are making me crazy. Is there somebody who has an idea of what is wrong with them?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you also have `aria-hidden="true"` applied as an attribute when the modal is hidden by default so that Flowbite can check whether the modal is being shown or not.

```
<button class="block text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button" data-modal-toggle="popup-modal">
  Toggle modal
</button>

<div id="popup-modal" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-50 md:inset-0 h-modal md:h-full">
  <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-md h-full md:h-auto">
    <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
      <button type="button" class="absolute top-3 right-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="popup-modal">
          <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>  
      </button>
      <div class="p-6 text-center">
        <svg class="mx-auto mb-4 w-14 h-14 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-200" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 8v4m0 4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
        <h3 class="mb-5 text-lg font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Are you sure you want to delete this product?</h3>
        <button data-modal-toggle="popup-modal" type="button" class="text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-300 dark:focus:ring-red-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2">
            Yes, I'm sure
        </button>
        <button data-modal-toggle="popup-modal" type="button" class="text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-200 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 hover:text-gray-900 focus:z-10 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-600">No, cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for replying, i have added it but now the modal is showing behind the backdrop and therefore, I'm unable to click it..

Comment: Try to give z-index to your model like `z-10`